# How to mass edit some contact numbers?

Tags: contacts

I need to add a extra digit to some of my contact numbers. Depending on their local code, or if they have no local code at all, I need to add "9".
This is due increase in cellphone numbers in Brazil, etc.

Is there anyway to do this without a specific app?
If not, then which app could I use for that?